# Visual studio code takes 2-10 mins to start - takes 100% CPU & freezes system

Tags: performance, visual-studio-code

System specs  -

Windows 7 Ultimate 64 bit SP1.

AMD Sempron 140 2.7 GHz Processor,
8 GB RAM, 
On-board NVIDIA GeForce 7025/nForce 630a graphics chip-set

VSC Version: From 1.1 - Latest Visual Studio Code Insiders build. (tried almost all)

Tried various things like disable extensions / disable GPU etc. but no use.

Any help will be appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: Is it the Visual Studio tool, or your own code, which takes a long time to start? Did you consider installing some [linux distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_distribution)? Your question is off-topic here, and lacks details (what other programs are running, show output of some commands, etc....). https://superuser.com/ could be a better place (with much more details) to ask.

Comment: thanks for your response. there is no code. I'm just firing up the editor and this is the problem I can provide the CPU profile if that helps and its definitely the vscode exe that consumes about 92% of the CPU. I don't want to try out any linux distro for an editor. I have another older laptop with Win7 32 bit with 1gb RAM with vscode 1.1 and there's no issues in that. I have posted a complaint in the github repo as well where this stackoverflow link was suggested. Hence, my question.

Comment: None of the specs matter except for the disk and file system ( personally SSD is critical id rather an SSD with old P4 then a modern CPU and spindle disk)  which is not mentioned.. What folder is it opening try opening it with an empty folder eg code c:\src\ . Have you disabled anti virus ?

Comment: @user1496062 , thanks for your inputs! like i had mentioned before, i have not gotten to opening a folder in the editor yet. its just firing up the editor that freezes up the system. Also, it  it has nothing to do with the disk and file system. As it turns out, VS code doesn't work well with single CPU machines (single core processors) and as a matter of fact mine is a single core one. This has been confirmed by the MS folks. Thanks for your help anyways.

Comment: can the down-voter please justify the action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VS code doesn't work well with single core CPUs which was causing the system to freeze. luckily, my CPU had a core unlocking feature which makes an additional core available and that fixed the issue. thanks everyone for your help.